# R Optimisation - Integer Programming

Tags: r, optimization, lpsolve

I have tried to use the R package LPSolve and in particular the lp.transport function to solve a optimisation problem.  In my fictitious example below I have 5 office sites that I need to resource with a minimum number of employees and I have set up a cost matrix that determines the distance from each employees home to the office.  I want to minimize the total distance traveled to work whilst meeting the minimum number of employees per office.

Initially this was working as I was treating all employees as equal (1). however problems have started to occur when I rate each employee by how efficient they are.  For example I now want to say that officeX needs the equivalent of 2 engineers which might be made up of 4 engineers who are 50% efficient or 1 that is 200% efficient.  When I do this however the solution found will split a employee across a number of offices, what I need is a additional constraint so impose that a employee can only be at 1 Office.
Anyway hopefully that is enough background here is my example:

```
Employee <- c("Jim","John","Jonah","James","Jeremy","Jorge")
Office1 <- c(2.58321505105556, 5.13811249390279, 2.75943834864996, 
      6.73543614029559, 6.23080251653027, 9.00620341764497) 
Office2 <- c(24.1757667923894, 19.9990724784926, 24.3538456922105, 
      27.9532073293925, 26.3310994833106, 14.6856664813007) 
Office3 <- c(38.6957155251069, 37.9074293509861, 38.8271000719858, 
      40.3882569566947, 42.6658938732098, 34.2011184027657) 
Office4 <- c(28.8754359274453, 30.396841941228, 28.9595182970988, 
      29.2042274337124, 33.3933900645023, 28.6340025144932) 
Office5 <- c(49.8854888720157, 51.9164328512659, 49.948290261029, 
      49.4793138594302, 54.4908258333456, 50.1487397648236)

#create CostMatrix
costMat<-data.frame(Employee,Office1, Office2, Office3, Office4, Office5)

#efficiency is the worth of employees, eg if 1 they are working at 100% 
#so if for example I wanted 5 Employees
#working in a office then I could choose 5 at 100% or 10 working at 50% etc...
efficiency<-c(0.8416298, 0.8207991, 0.7129663, 1.1406839, 1.3868177, 1.1989748)

#Uncomment next line to see the working version based on headcount
#efficiency<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)

#Minimum is the minimum number of Employees we want in each office
minimum<-c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1)

#solve problem
opSol <-lp.transport(cost.mat = as.matrix(costMat[,-1]),
                 direction = "min", 
                 col.signs = rep(">=",length(minimum)), 
                 col.rhs = minimum, 
                 row.signs = rep("==", length(efficiency)), 
                 row.rhs = efficiency,
                 integers=NULL)

#view solution
opSol$solution 

# My issue is one employee is being spread across multiple areas, 
#what I really want is a extra constraint that says that in a row there
# can only be 1 non 0 value.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is no longer a transportation problem. However you still can solve it as a MIP model:
[image]

Comment: Hi Erwin, can you suggest a package in R I might want to look at to try and implement this?

Comment: You could use LpSolve.

Comment: Hi Erwin, I am struggling with the syntax. Are you able to provide a example? Thanks Tom

Comment: What syntax? The mathematical model or the call to the solver?